# Having trouble understanding this definition of javaScript function

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/sidonaldson/ZuPYM/

```
(function() {
  if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) 
  {
      $("e").innerHTML = "DeviceOrientationEvent";
      window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(e) 
      {
          // y-axis - yaw
          var g = e.gamma || 0;
          // x-axis - tilt
          var b = e.beta || 0;
          // z=axis - swivel
          var a = e.alpha || 0;
          // degree north
          var c = e.compassHeading || e.webkitCompassHeading || 0;
          // accuracy in deg
          var accuracy = e.compassAccuracy || e.webkitCompassAccuracy || 0;
          deviceOrientationHandler(g, b, a, c, accuracy);
      }, false);
  }     
  else
  {
      $("e").innerHTML = "NOT SUPPORTED #FAIL";
  }
})();
```

1. Why does the function have a format of `(function(...) {...}) ();` What is going on here I have never seen a function declared like this.
2. Is the `$` use a variable name like a `_` in other languages
3. How does this function keep on looping, in C++ you needed a while or for or recursion what is going on with the `function('e')`.

Comment: `$` is at the top of the fiddle. Here it means 'return the element on the page with ID="e"'. Note that's not exactly how jQuery works - for jQuery you'd need `$('#e')` to select the element with ID="e" and then you'd need to get the DOM element out of that or use jQuery's `.text()` instead of `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) why does the function have a format of (function(...) {...}) (); What is going on here I have never seen a function declared like this.

This is a so called IIFE(Instantly Invoked Function Expression), which is basically an unnamed function which gets called just when the compiler reaches its end.

Think of it as a simple named function:

```
function myFunc() {...my code...}
```

And then it is executed right after the declaration:

```
myFunc();
```

Now the IIFE:

```
(function() {...my code...})();
^--------------------------^^^
Parentheses to enclose the function, the last two are to invoke the function itself
```

> 2) is the $ use a variable name like a _ in other languages

Yes it is, but in this case it is a function which simply returns the element with id `e`(normally it is the jQuery library, a very common one).

> 3) how does this function keep on looping, in C++ you needed a while or for or recursion what is going on with the function('e').

The function doesn't loop, it executes just once.

**EDIT**: as @Rup pointed out, you could be referring to why the handler is executed every time the event is triggered. This is possible since the `window.addEventListener` function adds a handler to an event(in this case `deviceOrientation`) which will be called every time the event is triggered. For more information please refer to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), MDN is the best place(IMHO) to get informations about JS.

Comment: Looping: I think the point is it adds an event handler, i.e. it continues to be triggered afterwards which is why he thinks it's looping.

Answer (score 2):

1. This is an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). Basically, this function will execute immediately, without being explicitly called. Once you are more comfortable with javascript, I would strongly recommend you to read the link for IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expressions)
2. $ is for [jQuery](http://jquery.com). It is a javascript library for HTML manipulation among other things. In javascript, $ and _ and more non-alphanumeric characters are also quite frequently used to define variables. Generally, `$` stands for jQuery (but you can use it for anything else also). Similarly, `_` stands for underscore.js.
3. This function does not "keep on looping". It is a listener. It listens to the `DeviceOrientationEvent` event and executes only when the device orientation changes.

It seems you are very new to javascript. I'd recommend you get some experience in JS before diving into jQuery

Comment: Actually `$` isn't jQuery here. It's a function at the top of the fiddle he didn't bother quoting.

Comment: oh dear. It's a document.getElementById selector function. haha

Comment: Yea that is what I thought because he does not have a include for jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

1. The format you're talking about is called immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE). It is normally used in plugin / libraries definitions to make the declared function part of window/document or extend an existing object such as jquery.
2. $ is for jQuery, _ is for [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org), but it simply depends on what argument you're passing.
3. the function you're referring to is executed every time the event deviceorientation is fired. This is referred in javascript as a callback or a handler.

Answer (score 0):

1) This is an anonymous function being called and executed inmediately.

```
(function(argumentList) {
    // body
})(provideArguments);
```

2) $ is a global variable declared by the jQuery library.

3) if you use jQuery, you can directly affect all the results of your query. The library will loop for you. This code, for example, will select all anchor tags and foreach tag will execute the addClass method, putting the class "myClassName" to the results of the "query".

```
$('a').addClass('myClassName');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(...) {...}) ();
```

It means the code will be executed in the page directly.

```
$
```

This is the Jquery selector. cf : http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
e
```

This is an event object. cf : http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/